# What blend mode is this?

Tags: shader, image-processing, blending

[I asked this on Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/106742/116486) but was unable to get any relevant help from them.

I'm trying to reverse engineer a blending mode I've seen [on a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJS8R.png):

[image]

This image was created by someone else using *Adobe's Scene7* during a *Displacement Map Filter* operation. **I'm only interested in the blending mechanism, not the distortion**.

Unfortunately, I was unable to reproduce this effect on other raster graphics editors. It almost looks like the images were blended with *Multiply* followed by a recolor operation of some sort. Anyway, I'm trying to figure out the equation used for this type of blending.

If you look at the top left corner of where the images overlap, you can see just a little bit of the background leaking to the foreground image.

The original images have the same dimensions and can be found below:

[image]
[image]

Any idea on how to duplicate this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question definitively, I figured out that the blending used is a combination of **Multiply** and **Hue**.

After executing a *Multiply* blend on the input images, pass the result as the background for a *Hue* blend while using the same foreground image:

[image] [image]

*Background and foreground images for the Hue blend: on the left, the background (generated by a previous Multiply); on the right, the original foreground.*

The resulting image can be seen [on this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0akv7yq/9/). Don't panic! If you see the code you'll notice it is using the *luminosity* blend instead of the *hue* blend. I talked about this problem at the end of [my other answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/106807/116486).

[Equations](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/) for [all](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#blendingmultiply) [these](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#blendinghue) [blending](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#valdef-blend-mode-luminosity) modes can be found on [W3C website](https://www.w3.org).

Answer (score 1):

That looks like multiplying the front image by the luminance of the shirt behind it.

There are multiple definitions of luminance but for a start, I think you could assume your data is sRGB and follow the [transformation to CIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_reverse_transformation) to get the CIE Y component.